# iPhone SDK: How to check for IP-Validity?

Tags: iphone, ip-address, nspredicate

in my iphone app users can enter a specific ip-address/URL to connect to their own server and i'm trying to check the validity of the entered address. So if a user entered something like "1234" the app would throw an error because it does not "look" like an ip-address or a URL.
Right now i'm trying to accomplish this by using the following method:

```
- (BOOL)urlIsValid:(NSString *)address {

NSString *urlRegEx = @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:address];
}
```

And it I thought it was working just fine but now apparently even if I enter a correct ip-address the method will return "NO".
Any ideas on what could be wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)
Especially the Listing 1, where the code says `if (theConnection)`

Comment: That didn't really provide any help, because it does not provide any documentation on how to check if the entered ip address conforms to a certain standart...

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't quite get what you just said. What do you mean by **certain standard** of IP address. Can you give an example showing what you consider valid and what is invalid. <br> I merely assumed that you wanted to check the existence of a server

Comment: Well, theoretically a user could enter anything as an ip-address in the provided textfield. So a user could enter something completely random like: "bla" or "$$". In that case I need a method which checks if the entered text is actually a potential candidate for an ip-address and after that I can check if there's actually a server behind the address. I hope thats better understandable.

Comment: Yes, but i already know how to check for the existence of a server i just don't know how to check for the validity of the ip address

Comment: Effectively, you want to check 2 things. <br>1) Check format of the _entered_ ip address. [Are you the same Chris?][1]  <br>2) Existence of the server. This is already answered<br><br> 

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154545/iphone-sdk-how-to-check-if-ip-entered-by-user-is-valid

Comment: Yes I am the same chris.. And the reason i am asking this again is because the answer from the other question doesn't seem to work...

Comment: One rule: Regular Expressions!

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSPredicate` for this is overkill, and isn't really what it was intended for.  You should use [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for doing a regex match.  However, to fully validate an IP address with a single regular expression would be cumbersome, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I'm validating ip address with this way, try to add http(s) prefix so, it should be work.

```
NSString *urlRegEx = @"^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
NSPredicate *ipTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
return [ipTest evaluateWithObject:address];
```

Good luck